# `ls` causes Segmentation Fault on a specific directory

Tags: linux, redhat, segmentation-fault, ls

I used `$HOME/.local` as prefix to install some applications without root access. There is one directory inside `$HOME/.local` that I can't execute `ls` command:

```
[tuananh@server lib]$ ls
Segmentation fault
[tuananh@server lib]$ cd ..
[tuananh@server .local]$ ls lib
audit                    libform.a         
libncurses.a             libopenblas.so.0
...
[tuananh@server .local]$
```

What could posibly be the reason for that? `uname -a` for my server:

```
Linux server 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 12 14:18:09 CDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**EDIT**: Output of `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ls`. I found some libraries loaded from this directory. So now what should I do to find the one that cause the problem?

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff831b8000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000003d94800000)
librt.so.1 (0x00007fdcde5a3000)
libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x0000003d95c00000)
libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x0000003d97c00000)
libc.so.6 (0x00007fdcde1f5000)
libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdcddff1000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d92c00000)
libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdcdddd3000)
libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x0000003d96800000)
```

Comment: Please run `strace ls` and post the last few lines before the segfault in your question.

Comment: Server is likely hacked. Who's the administrator?

Comment: Now I realize all commands, except `pwd` is returned `Segmentation fault`, for example `ls`, `java`, `python`, `strace`, `sh` and more. It only happens when current directory is `$HOME/.local/lib`

Comment: Does the good old `echo *` work in that directory?

Comment: Call your administrator or whoever is responsible for the server.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen it does work! Do you know what happen?

Comment: @ewwhite I still want to resolve this problem by myself first before calling administrator

Comment: @hvtuananh did you check my answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely you have some library installed in there that gets loaded instead of the system ones when you execute a command in there and it is binary incompatible with the commands in your system. It's probably something related to glibc or so.

You can confirm this by running `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ls` and examining the output to see if it includes any of the files in the current directory.

Comment: Yes I've updated my question. Please take a look, thank you!

Comment: Do you have LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable set? If yes, what is its value? `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: It was set to `some_non_related_dir:` I guess the culprit is the trailing `:` since it will include current directory, correct? The reason for the trailing `:` is this line in `.bash_profile`: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= some_non_related_dir:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and now can `ls` any directory without problem! So now problem is definitely some library in my custom `lib` directory.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to find with lib causes problem?

Comment: You can install debugging packages for libs and coreutils and use gdb. Not sure. There may be some easier way but if it were me, I would create a bash loop that takes the libraries one by one and sees when the problem is fixed. Note that there may be multiple ones so you may need to recursively loop multiple times through the libraries to see exactly.